# Dart: Generate random lat-long

Tags: flutter, dart

I wanna test clustering in flutter with big input, for ex 1000.000
So, how to generate a random lat long using dart. or it could be better if there is a json generator tool for that

Answer (score 4):

You could do something like this:

```
final random = Random();
double randomLat = -90 + random.nextDouble() * 90 * 2;
double randomLng = -180 + random.nextDouble() * 180 * 2;
print('$randomLat, $randomLng');
```

Or

```
final random = Random();
double nextDouble(num min, num max) => min + random.nextDouble() * (max - min);

double randomLat = nextDouble(-90, 90);
double randomLng = nextDouble(-180, 180);
print('$randomLat, $randomLng');
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need a random lat/lon, just generate two random numbers in the right range.  Lat is between -90 and 90.  Lon is between -180 and 180.

Answer (score -1):

Try the dartamaker package on pub.